# When I try to run npm start

Tags: angular

When I run the following commands:

```
ubuntu@ubunt_server:~/cost/Angular/ang/quickstart$ npm start
angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart /home/ubuntu/cost/Angular/ang/quickstart
npm run build
angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build /home/ubuntu/cost/Angular/ang/quickstart
tsc -p src/
```

I receive the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                                                                                                                                                             ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-10-03T09_24_51_022Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                                                                                                                                                             ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-10-03T09_24_51_063Z-debug.log
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: run npm install and see if there is any error

Comment: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 is two years old now. I recommend to start with the quickstart in angular.io (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

or

```
 npm cache clean
```

after running above ,delete **node_modules** folder . now install dependencies again by running below code

```
 npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

And what's in `/home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-10-03T09_24_51_063Z-debug.log` ?

Comment: This is not an answer !

Comment: @PrathapG well I dont like to make random guess - usually these log files contain the root cause for the errors.

Comment: Yes we can ask it from a comment